# Git clone from github

Tags: sublimetext2

If I want to install a package into Sublime Text 2, I can use the Package Control plugin. But say I want to install a package that is not available through that means.

I am told to 'git clone' from github and the command line is usefully included eg:

git clone https://github.com/mpmont/ci-snippets.git ci-snippets

But I cannot find an explanation of how to use it. I've tried pasting it into the console but just get 'Syntax Error'

I'm using Windows 7.

Help!

Comment: Have you installed git for windows? http://git-scm.com/download/win

Comment: also this would help: https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realize you may just be cloning but you may also add the repository to package control, then install it through that.

To add a repository through package control, open the command palette and enter `Package Control: Add Repository`. Then input the URL. Note this URL should not contain the `.git` extension. Then, you can install the package via package control as you would with any other package. Of course, cloning also works, but just thought I would throw this out there if you didn't want to worry about doing all the git stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You have to [install git](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) first.

After you have installed (msys)git, open windows explorer, right click on your target folder and choose "Git Bash". In this shell you can use

```
git clone https://github.com/mpmont/ci-snippets.git ci-snippets
```

to clone the repository.